# Android seek bar thumb customization

Tags: android, android-custom-view, seekbar

I am trying to create a seekbar. It has to look like below in picture.

[image]

Here is my seekbar in layout:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/progress_bar_height"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_seek_bar"
    android:thumbOffset="0dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/progressbar_thumb"
    android:max="100"/>
```

Here is progressbar_thumb drawable XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img_grabber_body"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img_grabber_knob_long"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

There are two different images in thumb one vertical line and round knob. My problem is how to use such thumbs in Android seekbar. If I set the thumb in XML it considers width of thumb as width of round knob. Because of this it leaves some space between thumb and progress as you see in below images. I can customize view to show complete thumb but how to remove this extra space around the thumb?

[image]

Comment: There are a bunch of libraries you can use for Range bars. Take a look at this link https://android-arsenal.com/tag/83. Use whatever library you like the most, or take those libraries and customize them as you like.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem.
I found really useful [this code](https://gist.github.com/bhargavms/8ecaffb8c5b91935482d7ebf37672699#file-seekbarwithhint-java-L78).

You just have to change where the text is drawn in the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)`

Hope this could help.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is my code that put the label with the progression percentage under the seekbar thumb. You just have to change values of `label_x` and `label_y` in the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` to change the position where the label is drawn.

```
public class SeekBarWithHint extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar {
private final int MIN_PROGRESS_VALUE = 0;
private final int MAX_PROGRESS_VALUE = 100;

private Paint mSeekBarHintPaint;
private int mHintTextColor;
private float mHintTextSize;

public SeekBarWithHint(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public SeekBarWithHint(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.SeekBarWithHint,
            0, 0);

    try {
        mHintTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.SeekBarWithHint_hint_text_color, 0);
        mHintTextSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.SeekBarWithHint_hint_text_size, 0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }

    init();
}

public SeekBarWithHint(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setMax(MAX_PROGRESS_VALUE);
    mSeekBarHintPaint = new TextPaint();
    mSeekBarHintPaint.setColor(mHintTextColor);
    mSeekBarHintPaint.setTextSize(mHintTextSize);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int label_x = (int) (getThumb().getBounds().centerX());
    int label_y = getHeight();
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(getProgress()) + "%", getProgress() > 95 ? label_x - 55 : label_x, label_y, mSeekBarHintPaint);
}

private void animateProgression(int progress) {
    final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "progress", MIN_PROGRESS_VALUE, progress);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
    this.setProgress(progress);
    this.clearAnimation();
}

public void setSeekbarProgress(int progress) {
    animateProgression(progress);
}
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Better use this [DescreteSeekBar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar) that do EXACTLY what you are looking for.

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I will edit my answer ASAP :)